# How to write integer and string together in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, output

```
coin :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
dollar :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
sen :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int

coin q d n p = (q * 25) + (d * 10) + (n * 5) + (p * 1)
dollar q d n p = (coin q d n p) `div` 100
sen q d n p = (coin q d n p) `mod` 100
```

Assume `(dollar q d n p)` is 6 and `(sen q d n p)` is 27.

How to write `"6 dollar and 27 sen"` in Haskell for the output?

I can do it in Python,

```
# [Input]

    dollar = 2 * 3
    sen = 3 * 9
    print(dollar, " dollar and ", sen, "sen")

# [Output]
# 6 dollar and 27 sen
```

Then, how to write it in Haskell so the output can be the same?

Comment: As a general suggestion, if you want to program in language X, it's best to avoid writing code in language Y and then trying to convert such code into X. Often, X and Y have different ways to approach the same task. In the case of Python and Haskell, these two languages are based on radically different paradigms, and translating between those is usually harder than rewriting the program from scratch. For instance, there's no assignment in Haskell, so even `dollar = 2*3` can not easily be simulated without resorting to very unidiomatic code.

Comment: we can't reuse same question entry to post completely unrelated questions, which invalidates the existing answers. it is against the rules of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

```
putStrLn $ (show dollar) ++ " dollar and " ++ (show sen) ++ "sen"
```

or (using module [`Text.Printf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html))

```hs
import Text.Printf

printf "%d dollar and %d sen\n" dollar sen
```